# Data Leakage Using InheritableThreadLocal

Tags: java, inheritable-thread-local

I'm using a threadpool to run some tasks in my application. Each task contains an object called TaskContext, which looks pretty much like this:

```
 public class TaskContext implements Serializable {
    private static InheritableThreadLocal<TaskContext> taskContextTL = new InheritableThreadLocal<>() ;

    private final String taskName ;
    private final String user;

    public TaskContext(String taskName, String user) {
        this.taskName= taskName;
        this.user = user ;
    }
       
    public String getTaskName() {
        return taskName ;
    }
    public static synchronized TaskContext getTaskContext() {
        return taskContextTL.get() ;
    }
    public static synchronized void setTaskContext(TaskContext context) {
        taskContextTL.set(context) ;
    }
}
```

I use InheritableThreadLocal because I need the task data to be inherited by children threads.

At the beginning of each task, I use the `setTaskContext(new TaskContext(taskName, user))` method to set the task parameters, and before the task ends- I use: `setTaskContext(null)` to clear this data.

The problem is that for some reason, when the same thread runs a different task, and for that thread I use the `getTaskContext().getTaskName()` method, I don't get the current task name but some previous task name that this thread ran.

Why is this happening? Why does setting InheritableThreadLocal value to null doesn't clear the data? How it can be avoided?

Thanks a lot for the help

**Update:**
I found a source online that claims this: "calling set(null) to remove the value might keep the reference to this pointer in the map, which can cause memory leak in some scenarios. Using remove is safer to avoid this issue."

But not sure what it means...

Answer (score 1):

The source that you found that claims "calling set(null) to remove the value might keep the reference to this pointer in the map, which can cause memory leak in some scenarios. Using remove is safer to avoid this issue." is https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/leak/RSPEC-5164.

Although I don't fully understand why they claim this I trust the people from sonarsource.com enough to consider this claim valid.

More to the point of your question they also provide a fix for this problem. Adapted to your code fragment it means that you should not use `setTaskContext(null)` to remove the TaskContext but rather create a method

```
public static void clearTaskContext() {
    taskContextTL.remove() ;
}
```

and use this method to remove the TaskContext.

Also note that I didn't make this method synchronized and also the synchronization in `getTaskContext()` and `setTaskContext()` is not needed. Since the `TaskContext` is stored in a `ThreadLocal` that is (as its name implies) local to a specific thread there can never be a synchronization issue with them

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the comment about the synchronization. I made the fix and it looks fine, I just wanted to understand more why it was wrong before.